# Capistrano: Unable to chdir or not a git archive

Tags: git, capistrano

It is the first time that I try to deploy a Rails app with Capistrano.

Here what happens when I call deploy:migrations:

```
$ cap deploy:migrations
  * executing `deploy:migrations'
  * executing `deploy:update_code'
    updating the cached checkout on all servers
    executing locally: "git ls-remote collimarco@foto-fiori.com:/home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git master"
collimarco@foto-fiori.com's password: 
  * executing "if [ -d /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git reset  --hard b38d7ae360a23c1660baceef571667b79e19769b && git clean  -d -x -f; else git clone  --depth 1 collimarco@foto-fiori.com:/home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout  -b deploy b38d7ae360a23c1660baceef571667b79e19769b; fi"
    servers: ["foto-fiori.com"]
Password: 
    [foto-fiori.com] executing command
 ** [foto-fiori.com :: out] Initialized empty Git repository in /mnt/local/home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy/.git/
 ** [foto-fiori.com :: out] collimarco@foto-fiori.com's password:
Password: 
 ** [foto-fiori.com :: out]
 ** [foto-fiori.com :: out] fatal: '/home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git': unable to chdir or not a git archive
 ** [foto-fiori.com :: out] fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    command finished
failed: "sh -c 'if [ -d /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git reset  --hard b38d7ae360a23c1660baceef571667b79e19769b && git clean  -d -x -f; else git clone  --depth 1 collimarco@foto-fiori.com:/home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy && cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy && git checkout  -b deploy b38d7ae360a23c1660baceef571667b79e19769b; fi'" on foto-fiori.com
```

The directory /home/collimarco/git/foto-fiori.git exists and it is a --bare repository! So, what is the problem?

Comment: Have you tried running the commands that capistrano is trying to run from the server in an SSH session? Specifically, cd /home/collimarco/foto-fiori.com/shared/cached-copy && git fetch  origin && git reset  --hard b38d7ae360a23c1660baceef571667b79e19769b && git clean  -d -x -f;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dreamhost was migrating my site to another server.